# SingleColumnValueFilter not working in Bigtable Emulator

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

It seems that the Bigtable emulator is not filtering properly when using the `SingleColumnValueFilter` as shown in the example below; however, this same code works correctly in the production version of Bigtable.

Incorrect Result output: "row1 row2 row3 row4"

Should have printed: "row3"

```
byte[] cf = "cf".getBytes();
byte[] cq = "cq".getBytes();
Connection conn = BigtableConfiguration.connect("fake-project", "fake-instance");
Admin admin = conn.getAdmin();
TableName testTableName = TableName.valueOf("testTable");
HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor(testTableName);
descriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(cf));
admin.createTable(descriptor);

byte[] val = { 0x1a };
byte[] val2 = { 0x11 };
byte[] val3 =  "a".getBytes();
byte[] val4 = "b".getBytes();

Table table = conn.getTable(testTableName);
table.put(new Put("row1".getBytes()).addColumn(cf, cq, val));
table.put(new Put("row2".getBytes()).addColumn(cf, cq, val2));
table.put(new Put("row3".getBytes()).addColumn(cf, cq, val3));
table.put(new Put("row4".getBytes()).addColumn(cf, cq, val4));

Scan scan = new Scan().setFilter(new SingleColumnValueFilter(cf, cq, CompareOp.EQUAL, val3));
// THIS wrongly prints all rows in the table rather than just row3
for(Result r: table.getScanner(scan)) {
    String row = new String(r.getRow());
    System.out.print(row);
}
```

Comment: What version of the emulator are you running? If you're using the latest one, please file a bug at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go.

Comment: Emulator:  gcloud beta 2019.02.22    https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1399

Comment: Please see fix at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732580/singlecolumnvaluefilter-not-working-in-bigtable-emulator#comment98180543_55732580

Comment: This was a bug and has been fixed per https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1399.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is correct.

This was a bug in an older emulator version (Emulator: gcloud beta 2019.02.22).

This bug has since been fixed (see original [report here](http://%20github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1399)).